# JavaScript: Imágenes verticales se suben horizontales

Tags: javascript

Subo imágenes mediante JavaScript a mi servidor.

Tengo un previsualizador para cuando las selecciono de mi equipo, al hacer esto, la imagen (solo si es vertical) se coloca horizontal (en el previsualizador), y al momento de subirla al servidor, sube como se ve, es decir horizontal.

[image: Imagen real en mi equipo]

[image: Imagen en mi previsualizador]

[image: Este es mi código JS]

Comment: puedes usar esta libreria https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image

Comment: Esto me pasa a menudo cuando importo imágenes en algunos programas. Creo que se debe a la orientación especificada en EXIF.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código como texto en lugar de como una imagen, de ese modo será más fácil de leer y podrá indexarse y buscarse. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.